# creating a FTP user in Linux command line

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm struggling in creating an FTP user on a Linux server using the command line.

- I installed `vsftpd`
- Then i created a user using multiple commands for multiple times like

```
sudo adduser --home /home/testuser testuser --no-create-home
```

- Added password to it,
- Edited `etc/vsftpd.conf` file,
- enabled `chroot_local_user=YES`,
- Added user name to config files, etc etc. But none seems to work.
- They are getting created as SFTP users. I disabled the SSH access and then it stopped for FTP too.
- What all I need is to do is simply set up an FTP user and jail them to a path without SSH access.
  Can anyone help?
  I had gone through a lot of posts. But still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying `vsftpd`,
I used `ProFTP` and it worked. I followed the below steps and it worked.

**ProFTP Setup in Linux:**

- Document Link
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-proftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04

```
sudo apt-get install proftpd (to install)
sudo apt-get remove proftpd (to uninstall)
```

- Edit the ProFTP configuration file located at `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` to update specific settings

```
sudo vi /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
```

- Make sure the ServerName and MasqueradeAddress are set to the current machine’s Public or Elastic IP Address.
- Set RequireValidShell to false. Set DefaultRoot to ~ to jail users to their home directories only.

```
ServerName                      "54.187.75.250"
ServerType                      standalone
MasqueradeAddress         54.187.75.250
RequireValidShell               off
DefaultRoot                     ~
PassivePorts                  50000 51000
<IfModule mod_facts.c>
    FactsAdvertise off
</IfModule>
```

**Creating an ftp user**

- Add a ftp user to the system

```
sudo useradd -m ftpuser (the -m option is to create a home directory for the user)
```

- Set user’s password

```
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

- At a later time, you may delete the user by executing

```
sudo deluser ftpuser
```

- Test if FTP server is up and running from a remote machine, login using the id/pwd of the newly created `ftpuser`
  Transfer files back and forth.
- Restart FTP server

```
sudo service proftpd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd start
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot more FTP serves like vsftpd, ProFTP, and PureFTP.
But with vsftpd there are known issues. That's right. You can use ProFTP and I followed the same method using ProFTP. It worked.

Comment: Did you try any other or only the ProFTP ?

Comment: Yes. I only used ProFTP. It worked so I didn't test with other ones.